# Multiplying radicals which include a variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the $\sqrt {2a}\sqrt {2a}$, $\sqrt{4a}$? Thanks! I know obviously $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}$ is $\sqrt{4}$, which is $2$, but what if there is a variable involved?

Comment: I think the answer should be $2a$: $\sqrt {2a}*\sqrt {2a}= {\sqrt {2a}}^2=2a$.

Comment: Well, a hint should be that $m*m = m^2$ always so $\sqrt{m}\sqrt{m} = (\sqrt{m})^2$ always.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a$ is positive,

$\sqrt{2a}×\sqrt{2a}=\sqrt{2a×2a}=\sqrt{4a^2}=\sqrt4×\sqrt{a^2}=2a$.

In general, multiplying the square root of a number, by the same square root, yields that number, because it is the same as **squaring the square root** of a number.

If $a$ is negative, let $b=-a$. Consider that $b$ is positive.

$\sqrt{2a}×\sqrt{2a}\\=\sqrt{2b×(-1)}×\sqrt{2b×(-1)}\\=\sqrt{2b}×i×\sqrt{2b}×i\\=\sqrt{2b}×\sqrt{2b}×i×i\\=2b×(-1)\\=-2b\\=2a$.

Comment: Except if $a$ is negative

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan It holds even if $a$ is negative (use $i$)

Comment: No I meant $\sqrt {a^2} = a$ does not hold when $a < 0$.

Comment: @Mohammad but $\sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{a}$ does equal $a$ even in the case that $a$ is negative.  Do not confuse $\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{a}$ with $\sqrt{a^2}$.  The question being asked is about the first, not the second.

Comment: That being said, @user_194421 Mohammad brings up an important point.  $\sqrt{2a}\cdot\sqrt{2a}$ is not necessarily the same thing as $\sqrt{2a\cdot 2a}$ in the case that $a$ is negative.  You did however say "assuming $a$ is positive" before the potentially problematic simplification, so it should have been a non-issue.

Comment: @JMoravitz I stated this  because _generally_ the primary root is considered.

Comment: Otherwise you get things like $1 = \sqrt 1 = \sqrt {(-1)(-1)} = \sqrt {-1}*\sqrt {-1} = i*i = i^2 = -1$.

Comment: Be careful that $\sqrt{a^2} \ne (\sqrt{a})^2$.  But by *definition* we *must* have $(\sqrt{a})^2 = a$.  That *is* what $\sqrt{}$ means.  So $\sqrt{2a}*\sqrt{2a} = (\sqrt{2a})^2 = 2a$.

Comment: @fleablood They are equal if $a$ is positive. I have put the proof if $a$ happens to be negative.

Comment: If $a < 0$ we *still* have $(\sqrt{a})^2 = a$.  That is the *definition* of $\sqrt{}$.  So you don't *need* a proof if $a < 0$.  But if $a < 0$ we don't have $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$ is *not* equal to $(\sqrt{a})^2 = a$.  But that's fine because we don't give a rat's patootie what $\sqrt{a^2}$ is... we only need to care about what $(\sqrt{a^2})^2$ is.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\sqrt{2a}\times\sqrt{2a}=(2a)^{\frac12}\times(2a)^{\frac12}=(2a)^{\frac12+\frac12}=2a.$$

Answer (score 0):

The square and the square root are inverses of each other so that

$$\sqrt x\sqrt x=\left(\sqrt x\right)^2=x$$ whateve $x$ can be (provided it is non-negative).

---

We also have

$$\sqrt{x\cdot x}=\sqrt{x^2}=x.$$

Answer (score 0):

To see weather or not $\sqrt{2a} \sqrt {2a}$ is the same as $\sqrt {4a}$, we just have to check wether or not $(\sqrt{2a} \sqrt {2a}) \cdot (\sqrt{2a} \sqrt {2a})=4a$.

But $(\sqrt{2a} \sqrt {2a}) \cdot (\sqrt{2a} \sqrt {2a})=(2a) \cdot (2a)=4a^2$

So $\sqrt{2a} \sqrt {2a}$ is **not** the same as $\sqrt {4a}$.